# Unexpected list overflow

Tags: html, css

I want the

## (Current Location)

directly under +Location in the inline list. What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to not make it overflow. http://jsfiddle.net/h3twR/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/h3twR/6/

```
#share-something-footer-left ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'helvetica neue', arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #3B5998;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So it was the fact I assigned a line-height?

Comment: Yep, you had 2 lines and each 30px high